# RLink error with dynamic libraries on Mac 10.12 with Mathematica v11

Tags: mac-os-x, rlink

## Background

Yes, there have been a lot of questions on `RLink` (quite a few on just how to get it working or installing packages). However none directly address loading RLink on MacOS. Older questions [Installing R packages using RLink on Mac OS X](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57783/installing-r-packages-using-rlink-on-mac-os-x) appear to somehow have `RLink` working.

When some posts have users with MacOS dealing with difficulty due to `RLink`, Szabolcs' post on [Setting up RLink for Mathematica](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html) has become the default response to these errors. (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123164/42578), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43732/42578), etc)

Namely, it states (for MacOS):

```
Needs["RLink`"]
SetEnvironment["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib"];
InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources", "RVersion" -> 3]
```

However, it is stated clearly in the documentation for [InstallR](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/ref/InstallR.html):

> "RHomeLocation"  Automatic location of the root of an external R distribution (currently **Windows** only)

Running the `SetEnvironment` command does not seem to cause any errors.

Another previous question [Does mathematica 9 on mac depend on these dynamic libraries?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35390/does-mathematica-9-on-mac-depend-on-these-dynamic-libraries) has an answer which states:

> none of the direct dependencies lies under /usr/local

which, in the terminal, `which R` is under:`/usr/local/bin/R`. Honestly, I do not even know if that is relevant.

## Question

Does anyone have a fool-proof solution for using `RLink` on MacOS?

Comment: RHomeLocation is not officially supported on OS X.  That's why I wrote that guide. It's basically a hack.  If you scroll to the bottom, you will find notes on how to get it working on OS X 10.11 and later—you need to do some extra work on that version because of the system integrity protection feature.  Have you tried following the instructions there?  If yes, what went wrong?  To be frank, I have not used RLink in a long time.

Comment: @Szabolcs I looked at the directory and that file `libjri.jnilib` does not exist...

Comment: Have you looked within subfolders of that folder?  There is a single subfolder there in v11, so I don't think it's hard to find if you look a bit ... In recent M versions it seems to have been moved. As I said, this is not supported, so there will not be a "foolproof" solution.  You can write to Wolfram Support and ask them to supports external R on OS X.

Comment: I just tested the instructions on my page with version 11.0.1, OS X 10.12 and R 3.3.2 (http://r-project.org/ distribution). It works fine.

Comment: @Szabolcs ok so then it is a matter of me not having the file?

Comment: Well have you searched? `FileNames["*.jnilib", 
 FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", 
   "RLink"}, Infinity]`

Comment: @Szabolcs yes I did a global find. It returned no results. I also evaluated the code above, no results.

Comment: Then you either don't have the same version I do, 11.0.1 for OS X, or your installation is damaged.

Comment: @Szabolcs that is what I thought, I will do a clean install of Mathematica.

Comment: What's your Mma version?  11.0.0 or 11.0.1?

Comment: I would like to "settle" this issue.  I asked others with M11.0.1 on OS X if they have this file.  They all said yes.  Have you managed to find it?

Comment: @Szabolcs I have M11.0.1, The `.jnilib` file was nowhere to be found, so I did I clean install. Yes, it seems to work now. :)